# Free resources for learning Arabic from English or Urdu

Tags: electronic-resources, arabic

I want to learn the Arabic language starting from basics. My native language is Urdu and I also understand English.

Please kindly compare free websites/resources in terms of being user friendly and of their ease of use.

Answer (score 2):

For a start, it makes perfect sense to seek out free resources to learn Arabic. Hope you already made up your mind on what variant of Arabic you want to learn. Whatever the case may be, though, Modern Standard Arabic (MSA) is your best bet, at least for a start.

There's no better way to start learning Arabic than to use the university of YouTube. Check out [this article](https://arabicgoals.com/youtube-learning-arabic-2020/) that reviewed and ranked the best 5 YouTube channels to learn MSA for the absolute beginner. After you gain a basic knowledge, then you can try to find some paid platform to learn Arabic at a more advanced level.

Comment: @engr, MSA stands for Modern Standard Arabic.

Answer (score 0):

*disclaimer*: I don't speak Arabic so have never tried any of these arabic resources.

The following links are to free resources surrounding learning arabic from english:

### Memrise

I have used this website before for italian, french and german and it has been a very user-friendly experience which optimises training patterns for optimum memorisation.
https://www.memrise.com/courses/english/arabic/

### Madinah

This is only for arabic and so I am unable to comment on it's user-friendliness or ease-of-use but it seems to be a very cosy website.
https://www.madinaharabic.com/learn-arabic.html

### Arabic Tripod

This seems to be the best currently avaliable location to learn arabic grammar and vocabulary. It also seems to be only reading and writing but will be likely useful nevertheless.
http://arabic.tripod.com/index.html

### Duolingo

The English --> Arabic course is still in the incubator (in development) and is not quite avaliable but it's worth keeping an eye on because in my opinion, duolingo is the best free online tool for language learning, not to mention how fun it can be!

Comment: Duolingo, Arabic from English: https://www.duolingo.com/course/ar/en/Learn-Arabic

Answer (score 0):

I found this book that teaches classical Arabic to Urdu speakers

https://www.4shared.com/office/2KqgKpJUiq/_Learn_Arabic_ebook__MaYalzam.html